# Android substring returning error

Tags: java, android, substring

Just testing the substring and can't seem to get it to work. I figured this would return "E"?

For some reason it returns blank though.

If I change it to substring(0,1) it returns "T" as expected...but 1,1 returns blank, and 2,1 throws an error.

```
 String newLetters="TEST";
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newLetters.substring(1,1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: The second argument is not the length (number of letters), it's the end index (exclusive). Try `newLetters.substring(1,2)` if you want just the `E`.

Comment: public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers are the start index and end index. So

```
string.substring(2, 2);
```

returns nothing because you are trying to get the string between the same index.

[**Link to documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,int%29)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
public String substring(int beginIndex,
                        int endIndex)
```

Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex(Inclusive)` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.

Thus the `length` of the substring is `endIndex-beginIndex.`

So in your case if you want `E` from `TEST`,  use

```
newLetters.substring(1,2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of substring are (beginning index, end index). It will return what is between these two, not including the latter. substring(1,2) will return 'E', as will substring(2) I believe. (2,1) will give an error because your ending index cannot be before your beginning index.

You may find this helpful: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm